# Differentiable functions using functions of functions

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have a question about differentiable functions, but it's using functions of functions and I'm unsure what I'm meant to be doing; I don't really understand the whole function of function stuff.

Question:
If $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, then $(f \circ f)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

True or False and substantiate.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what to do?

Comment: Do i just say f(x) = 2x so f'(x) = 2
and (f o f) = 2(2x)=4x

(f o f)'(x)=(4x)'=4, therefore it's false??

Comment: First find the domain of $g(x)=f o f(x)$ then find g'(x)

Comment: I don't understand, isn't the domain R?

Comment: You don't understand things like $\sin (e^x)?$

Answer (score 1):

It is true provided that $f(x)$ in the domain of $f'(x)$ (in other words, the derivative $f'$ is defined at each $y$ with  $y=f(x))$ since $$(f \circ f)'(x)=f'(f(x)).f'(x).$$